# В чём фишка рекурсии?

Tags: рекурсия, задание-на-собеседовании

Почему все так любят в собеседованиях и тестах задачи на рекурсию?

Как показывает лично моя практика в жизни и реальных проектах необходимость в этом очень низкая, чаще используются foreach, for тем не менее с завидным упорством всем стараются оценивать именно по ней ))

Comment: Потому что она сложнее? На простых задачах не так легко отличить умного соискателя от не очень умного. (Хотя можно, если постараться.)

Comment: Я тоже на практике редко использовал рекурсию (хотя иногда без нее трудно), но если соискатель плохо понимает принцип рекурсии, то вообще в алгоритмах, скорее всего, так себе. Это как своеобразный индикатор, на сколько быстро человек врубается в алгоритмы.

Comment: @VladD а что в ней сложного?

Comment: @pavel: Вопрос философский :) На мой взгляд, она сложнее,  чем обычная итерация, потому что рекурсивный подход предполагает некоторую степень абстрактности мышления.

Comment: @VladD вот вспоминаю я, как на какой-то олимпиаде стек забыли ключом прописать на с++ и я писал DFS (модификацию) без рекурсии, что-то получилось значительно сложнее)

Comment: @pavel: Это потому, что вам пришлось работать с естественно рекурсивной структурой (деревом). Обычно рекурсивные структуры данных не так часто попадаются, поэтому естественные алгоритмы преимущественно итеративны.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ряд задач, для решения которых лучше всего подходит именно рекурсия. Например, обход древовидных структур. Конечно, используется она гораздо реже, чем обычные циклы, однако практически любой программист рано или поздно с ней сталкивается. Её использование на собеседованиях как раз и можно этим объяснить - с одной стороны любой уважающий себя программист должен знать, что это такое, а с другой стороны используют её не то что бы часто, поэтому есть вероятность, что совсем слабый кандидат ничего путного не вспомнит, опытный сможет рассказать о пользе рекурсии из собственного опыта, а человек без большого опыта, но с головой на плечах и/или с достаточной теоретической базой,  сможет хотя бы рассказать что-то по памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с первым пунктом ответа Zealint, но категорически не согласен ни со вторым пунктом, ни, тем более с выводами.

> Как показывает лично моя практика в жизни и реальных проектах необходимость в этом очень низкая, чаще используются foreach

Ну вот именно это и хочет выяснить работодатель; понимание того факта, что цикл и рекурсия - это два совершенно разных алгоритма с различными областями использования; и наличие опыта решения задач, для которых требуется рекурсия.

Хотя лично я бы не просил писать на собеседовании писать код рекурсии, а дал бы две задачи на обход дерева, одна из которых решается циклом, а вторая - рекурсией, и просто спросил бы как претендент решал бы каждую. Как раз чтобы отсечь знакомых с рекурсией понаслышке, применивших бы ее для поиска родителя.

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, есть две причины популярности таких вопросов.

1. Проверка абстрактного мышления. Согласитесь, что нужно держать в голове некую воображаемую модель, в которой функция вызывает саму себя (особенно интересно, когда 2-3 функции взаимно вызывают друг друга), при этом программа не зацикливается, работает правильно и не рушит стек. Чтобы делать это всегда правильно, нужно хотя бы интуитивно владеть аппаратом метода индукции из математики, а это связано со способностью человека в принципе мыслить логически. Разумеется, рекурсия - это не единственная хорошая вещь для проверки такой способности.
2. Низкий уровень культуры работодателей (или тех, кто проводит собеседование). Как правило, типичные задачи на рекурсию (переделать цикл в рекурсию, посчитать сумму ряда через рекурсию), коих полно задают здесь на SO, являются абсолютно бесполезными, так как в цикле всё решается правильнее. Вас либо просто проверяют - будете ли вы беспрекословно выполнять задание, даже если оно УБОГОЕ и ТУПОЕ (им не нужно, чтобы у вас было своё мнение), - либо они сами слабо представляют себе, зачем на самом деле нужна рекурсия... попросите их сами, чтобы написали алгоритм Карацубы без рекурсии. Вот это я понимаю - задача.

Мой совет, не унижайте себя, если вам дают такие задачи - разворачивайтесь и уходите, это не ваше место. Если конечно, вам не важно именно это место работы. Если вы пойдёте на поводу у тупых вопросов и будете с готовностью на них отвечать - вы так и будете у них работать над тупыми задачами всё время.

Имхо.

Comment: мне кажется совет слишком категоричен, есть много задач, где рекурсия существенно уменьшает число строк в коде. Конечно мы понимаем, что *любой* алгоритм можно писать без рекурсии, но зачем?

Comment: Вы правы. Но то, о чём вы говорите, я подразумевал в пункте 1. Тот же алгоритм Карацубы или Тоома-Кука лучше писать **только** с рекурсией. Число строк может сократиться в разы. Я выразил своё мнение с позиции своего взгляда на современную IT-сферу. В области реализации алгоритмов такие вопросы вообще не возникают.

Answer (score -2):

Потому что некоторые задачи намного быстрей и проще выразить рекурсивно. И часто такие решения хороши из-за их большей сопровождаемости. Не везде будет много проходов, поэтому умение написание рекурсивный алгоритм очень ценно.

Comment: А можно тем кто голосует против обосновать, в чём я не прав? Может что-то новое узнаю.

Answer (score -2):

Потому что работодатель не хочет видеть в коде своего продукта лесенку из foreach. Если кандидат не знает про рекурсию, то спрашивать более сложные вопросы не имеет смысла.